# How do I get the time in seconds from epoch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, epoch, gettime

I assume I should be able to do it like so:

```
var date = Math.round((new Date).getTime() / 1000);
console.log(date);
```

However, that is logging:

```
301332453318
```

Which if I run through this convertor ( http://www.epochconverter.com/ ) it outputs the date as being:

```
GMT: Wed, 06 Nov 11518 03:13:03 GMT
```

Is it clearly not the year 11518 right now and my system time is correct so why is the Javascript time wrong - or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks, 
Thomas

Comment: It works fine when I try it, but I get a much less weird answer than you do. Current value for me (from your first expression) is 1332453704. Maybe your `console.log()` is messed up because that leading "30" is causing your problem.

Comment: Are you sure your system time is correct? I just ran your code on Chrome's developer tools, and I get 1332453724 (the right time)...

Comment: And for me it's 1332453705. Seems fine.

Comment: @Pointy see my answer for strange anomaly.

Comment: @darkajax see my answer for strange anomaly.

Comment: @Supr see my answer for strange anomaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is weird. If I look at the time in the console it is correct, but if I highlight it and copy it for some reason chrome (or maybe OSX) is prepending the 30 onto it... WTF? Any ideas why?

[image]

In the image look at the logged time: 1332454189 (the correct time) but the 'highlighted' value (which is what I copied and pasted into the epoch convertor) for some reason has the 30 prepended onto it as evidenced by the "Search Google for '301332454189'"

Any ideas why?

Comment: bizarre ... my Chrome isn't doing that but it sure looks like that's what your issue is.  Well at least you know that your code is OK :-)

Comment: Yes my code is good. And bizarre indeed. Thanks for the input.